# RMI: serializable and remote objects

Tags: java, rmi, serializable, remoteobject

I have a certain problem: I'm using RMI to communicate between server and client.

```
public class RemoteMap
    extends java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject
    implements RemoteMapInterface {

 private TreeMap<String, GeneralSprite> sprites;
...
```

This is my remote object. But I want the client to be able to change this object's content. And after the change the server can execute some operation based on this.

Example at the client side:

```
map = (RemoteMapInterface) (registry.lookup("map"));
map.getSprites.get("object1").setDx(-1);
```

I'm using serialiable on the GeneralSprite, but I guess it passed by value. So when I did some changes at the GeneralSprite, it wasn't transported to the server . Do I have to make GeneralSprite to an Remote object too? Or is it even possibly?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad english, I hope you can understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything which does not implement the `Remote` interface, whether directly or indirectly, will get serialized for the remote method invocation. So it’s a “call-by-copy” behavior. You can implement a new `Map` which implements `Remote`, but you can also add a method like `setDx(String spriteName, int value)` to your `RemoteMapInterface` and implement it as `sprites.get(spriteName) .setDx(value);` on the server side.

Comment: Thanks, finally I could solve the problem with your help. But in the end, I think I wont use RMI. I'm developing a game, so I need to update real-time my server. And it looks like RMI isn't the best solution for it. Anyway thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Everything which either does not implement Remote *or which is not currently exported* will be serialized.